# Anyway to force pandas to not cache objects used as index?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

class DemoObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(((DemoObj('a0'), DemoObj('b0')),
                                      (DemoObj('a1'), DemoObj('b1')),
                                      (DemoObj('a0'), DemoObj('b0')),
                                      (DemoObj('a1'), DemoObj('b1'))))

print(len({id(e) for i in df.index for e in i}))
```

This outputs 4, but I need it to output 8.

Just to show that this is due to some caching logic in the implementation of `pd.MultiIndex`:

```py
indexes = ((DemoObj('a0'), DemoObj('b0')),
           (DemoObj('a1'), DemoObj('b1')),
           (DemoObj('a0'), DemoObj('b0')),
           (DemoObj('a1'), DemoObj('b1')))

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indexes)

print(len({id(e) for i in indexes for e in i}))
print(len({id(e) for i in df.index for e in i}))
```

outputs

```py
8
4
```

Comment: It printed 8 for me.

Comment: ... amending that. If I paste into the shell I get 8. If I make a .py file, I get 4. That's because the strings are interned in the latter case, so multiple DemoObj objects have the same hash.

Comment: @tdelaney That's almost what I was afraid of... To make matters worse, if I change `__hash__` to return a unique value (ie adding a random number) I get a weird pandas error about categorical categories having to be unique.

Comment: Having `__hash__()` return `id(self)` raises the count to 6, so that's *sort of* an improvement...

Comment: @sj95126 Does it? I get the same `ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique` error (pandas 1.3.3)

Comment: this is not a pandas issue though - `set([id(DemoObj('a0')), id(DemoObj('a0'))]`) returns just 1 value

Comment: @AsishM. It is a pandas issue. In your example the interpreter is smart enough to reuse the same memory location. I added an example to show that there is some sort of caching going on in the implementation of `pd.MultiIndex`

Comment: @DeepSpace: Odd, pandas 1.3.3 here as well.

Comment: Hm, I'm under the impression that it should be `4`, the same reason why `len(set(indexes)) == 2`. Pandas' index works similar as sets or dictionary keys for that matter.

Comment: @QuangHoang But pandas allows non-unique indexes so I'm not sure I'm following that logic

Comment: You do have a point there, but depending on what you mean by *non-unique*. I'm saying that in other implementations (`set`), the two class instances are identical if `__eq__` returns `True`, so I can see the reason behind number `4`. Note that you can still slice `df.loc[indexes[2][0]]` even though the object is not in the index. On the other note, two *equal* instances having different hashes raises a serious alarm on me.

Comment: I mean if you read Python's construction of a set/dictionary, then you'd see why the object with existing `hash`/`__eq__` value is not added to the set.

Answer (score 1):

### What is this?

What you're seeing is something called *[factorization](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).* Factorization is intended to save memory in MultiIndex by re-using the same object multiple times.

Factorization is implemented within MultiIndex. You can see this happen inside the [MultiIndex.from_arrays() method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/56d82a9bd654e91d14596e82e4d9c82215fa5bc8/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L501):

```py
    def from_arrays(...):
        [...]
        codes, levels = factorize_from_iterables(arrays)
```

(Note: `from_tuples()` calls `from_arrays()`, so this is still relevant to your use case.)

### Why is this here?

Why does a MultiIndex factorize, when a single column Index doesn't?

This is speculation, but I would guess that the reason is that it is common to have a DataFrame with an index like this:

```
year product_type
2019 shoes
2019 hats
2019 pants
2020 shoes
2020 hats
2020 pants
```

In this example, the product_type level of the index has only 3 unique elements, and so benefits a large amount from being factorized. In other situations, where the index is unique or nearly unique, there is no gain from de-duplicating index objects.

That's likely why MultiIndex factorizes.

### How do I bypass this?

If you don't want your index objects de-duplicated, you have a few options:

1. **Change your index objects.** Make your object check for reference equality and not semantic equality. Two different objects with the same content will no longer compare as equal.

   You can change `__eq__()` of SomeObj to this:

   ```
       def __eq__(self, other):
           return self is other
   ```

   MultiIndex will still try to de-duplicate your index objects, but it won't do anything.
2. **Don't use MultiIndex.** The regular Index doesn't factorize.
3. **Construct your own levels and codes.** The purpose of `from_tuples()` is to make it easier to factorize a list of tuples, but you can also construct a MultiIndex without it.

   You can produce the levels like this:

   ```
   levels = [np.array(e) for e in zip(*indexes)]
   ```

   And the codes just count up in sequence 0, 1, 2, ...

   ```py
   codes = [np.arange(len(level)) for level in levels]
   ```

   Now, if you just create a MultiIndex like this, you get an error:

   ```
   ValueError: Level values must be unique
   ```

   But you can bypass this error by turning off verify_integrity.

   ```
   df.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=levels, codes=codes, verify_integrity=False)
   ```

   I don't know if turning off integrity checking causes problems elsewhere. YMMV.